# C: How can I exec() my program with the same command line arguments as my running program

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to reset my program when it receives a `SIGSEGV` by using `ececl()` in my signal handler. But, my current program needs commandline arguments to start that I can pass via `execl()` + 1 extra argument `"RESTART"` to notify the program that it just restarted instead of a fresh start.

But how can I pass my argv[] via exec()?

Objective: 
`execl("./myprog","./myprog",argv[1],argv[2],...,argv[argc],"RESTART");`
OR
`execl("./myprog","./myprog","RESTART",argv[1],argv[2],...,argv[argc]);`

Comment: Have a look at `execv`.

Comment: *“I am trying to reset my program when it receives a `SIGSEGV`”* I hope you’re doing that for the right reasons…

Comment: it's not a good idea to have the application try to restart itself. Instead, you could write a script that wraps your application, and restarts it when it crashed. Or you could use systemd to do the restart after a crash.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The proposed use of an `exec()` function does the same without creating a dependency on a wrapper script.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : it's not really the same. A segmentation fault is a serious issue, potentially involving eg. memory corruption - running anything after that should not be relied upon. Additionally, calling `exec` in a signal handler has its own risks (eg. the new process is executed as if it was run inside the signal handler - among other things, the caught signal will be blocked). And finally, after an `exec`, the new process inherits a variety of aspects from the original process - some of which might cause issues (things like the current working directory).

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah, I am masking SIGSEGV for a reason, because, I have a client program that is requesting some servicea from the target program and the client requests (under rare & unique situations) cause the inocent target program to generate SIGSEGV and I am trying to make it fault tolerant under that scenario... Hope I make sense!

Comment: @Sander De Dycker: That is correct, SIGSEGV is indeed a critical point of failure, but I cannot let my service/program to be down until I analyze and fix the problem, right? So I am ofcourse logging all the error information at that point before restarting my program for later reference. I am also maintaining conf file to initialize current working directoryand many other info to be set at restart, so I asume my program can resume normal behaviour on restart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save argv in a global, either from main:

```
static char **Argv;
int main(int c, char **v) { Argv = v; //...
```

or from a gcc constructor:

```
static char **Argv;
__attribute__((constructor))
static void ctor(int c, char **v) { Argv = v; }
```

Then you can do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static char **Argv;

static void hndlr(int s)
{
    execv("/proc/self/exe", Argv);
    _exit(127);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Argv = argv;

    struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = hndlr, .sa_flags = SA_NODEFER };
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0);

    sleep(1);
    fputs("start\n", stderr);

    //keep re-executing the same program
    raise(SIGSEGV);
}
```

Note that without the SA_NODEFER, you'll only see the message twice, because SIGSEGV will be blocked during the second run of the executable.

While this should be defined (especially if you add a signal stack so that you can handle stack overflows with this too), wrappers scripts/programs are a safer and more robust way of doing this. With the SISEGV handler approach, you aren't really starting from scratch -- you are inheriting signal masks, effective uids/gids, workings directories, open file descriptors, etc. etc., whereas with a wrapper script you start from a well defined state.

Answer (score 3):

[Use `execv()`:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <unistd.h>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The `execv()`, `execvp()`, and `execvpe()` functions provide an array of
>          pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
>          available to the new program.  The first argument, by convention,
>          should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.
>          The array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer.

Perhaps like this:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    ...
    int rc = execv( "./myprog", argv );
}
```

You may need to modify specific values in `argv` or create an entirely new argument array to fit what you need.